# highcharts.js: static ticks spaced equally apart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jpgraph

Is it possible to have static tick marks equally apart even though the difference between the tick marks are not equal?  For example here is how I have my yAxis set up in a column chart:

```
yAxis: 
{
    min: 0,
    title: 
    {
        text: 'Velocity (in/sec)'
    },
    labels: 
    {                           
        overflow: 'justify'
    },
    tickPositions: [0.01, 0.10, 1.00, 10.00]
}
```

I want 0.01-0.10 to take up 33% of the graph, 0.10-1.0 to take up 33%, and 1.0-10.0 to take up the remaining 34%, with the columns falling into place according to their values.

I have some JPGraphs that have this functionality and am hoping it can be transferred to highcharts.js.

Comment: Make it a log scale graph? See: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want a [logarithmic axis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.type).

```
    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        min: 0.01,
        max: 10
    },
```

Here's a fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3CLxX/).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Highcharts does not support automatic creation of histograms, but you can add a category to the xAxis with the desired labels, and then create arrays of data to match these.

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['0.01', '0.10', '1.00', '10.00']
        },
series: [{
            data: [10, 52, 1, 0]        
        }]
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories